# Parsing values from Google news

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, cheerio

From Google news I'm attempting to parse the results. For example, parse the title and text from the search "latest movie releases", here is the URL:

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ALeKk01qAUzdE7UzK9aWPL9MYALHEk6aiQ%3A1599313588168&ei=tJZTX6vwCdWr1fAP6eGiyAk&q=latest+movie+releases&oq=latest+movie+releases&gs_l=psy-ab.3...299098.305542.0.305681.31.25.3.2.2.0.161.1719.22j3.25.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.13.704...0j33i10k1.0.9TgaNbbee40

The results appear to use #rso in the id:

[image]

But the iterator over `$('#rso').each` is empty. What id or css element should I select in order to iterate over the divs of search results ?

Iterator code:

```
$('#rso').each(function (i, element) {
    console('div level 1')
    var title = $(this).find('.r').text();
    var link = $(this).find('.r').find('a').attr('href').replace('/url?q=', '').split('&')[0];
    var text = $(this).find('.st').text();
    var img = $(this).find('img.th').attr('src');
    savedData.push({
      title: title,
      link: link,
      text: text,
      img: img
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$$` instead

```
$$('#rso > div')
```

[image]

Reference

[Console Utilities API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities)

> $(selector) is alias to document.querySelector()
>
> $$(selector) is alias to document.querySelectorAll()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#rso > div').each(...
```

Comment: thanks but this does not fix and produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one.

```js
let data = {};
document.querySelectorAll("#rso").forEach(elem => {
    let hrefs = []; 
    let imgs = [];
    elem.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(aElem => {
        hrefs.push({href: aElem.getAttribute("href")});    
    });
    elem.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(iElem => {
        imgs.push({src: iElem.getAttribute("src")});        
    });
    data.links = hrefs;
    data.images = imgs;
})
```

Please note that each card is having two images one is the icon on the left as thumbnail and the other is the actual image. **So the images list length will be 2 * length of links list.**